# How to copy multiple files showing all on the same copying progress dialog

Tags: vb.net, copying, system.io.file

I've created a multiple drive copier. What happens is that all removable drives are listed in a listbox (lstDrives)
then the source of the folder I want to copy to the drives is (txtBrowseFolder.Text)

It loops through the list of drives and copies to each drive.
Now my issue is that, since it is a loop, it takes it time to copy one drive after the other, 
BUT I wish it will copy all at once using the same copying dialog; showing all the copying progress of each item being copied.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdCopyDrives_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCopyDrives.Click
    Dim sDrive As String
    strSource = txtBrowseFolder.Text

    Dim d As Integer

    For d = 0 To lstDrives.Items.Count - 1
        sDrive = lstDrives.Items(d).ToString

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(strSource, sDrive, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you start your program running so that the Windows copy dialog appears and at the same time manually copy a different drive, does the copy dialog now appear as you want, or does another dialog appear? That is, does Windows automatically combine them for you? If so, I can suggest something.

Comment: You see, it combines into only one progress dialog if copying manually but in this case, since the copying command is in a loop, it copies one after the other, thus one progress shows, then goes off then the next comes then goes off after completion of each.

Comment: What happens if you try what I suggested?

Comment: yes. I did.  i realized it didnt join the ongoing progress because its on the same drive, but unless the files are being copied on different drives. :D

Answer (score 0):

It does look like it copies all the drives.  Unless you mean by "all at once" something other than one code line.

To show progress, use the ProgressBar Control.  You know the total number of drives to process (lstDrives.Items.Count) so you can update the bar just before your Next staetment in the For...Next loop.

Comment: No I am not seeking to show a progress for the entire sequence of copying progress. I am seeking to make all the copying show on the same Windows copying dialog (in Windows 10) just as you will see when you are manually copying multiple files and the progress for each showing at the same time

Comment: @SamuelDexter  Then you will have to create your own dialog box containing a multi-line TexctBox or ListBox.  Do you need some example code to do that?